# How to make SOAP calls from web application with Signed Request authentication?

Tags: visualforce, soap-api, soap

We have a **web application**, working as a **Visualforce** page, with **Signed Request** authentication. Is there a way of making **SOAP API calls from backend**, using the token provided in "client" field of CanvasRequest object?

This topic describes how to make SOAP calls having OAuth authentication: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_guidelines_yourtools.htm - would it work with the access token retrieved via signed request authentication? What should we put into "oauth_consumer_key", "oauth_signature" and other required fields?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [CanvasRequest](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/platform_connect/Content/canvas_request_object.htm) the oauthToken has the distinct look of a SessionId to me.

> "client":
>       {
>           "instanceId":"06Px000000002JZ",
>           "instanceUrl":"http://instance.salesforce.com:8080",
>           "oauthToken":**"00Dx0000X00Or4J!ARQAQJ34YL8gKowP65p8FDHkvk.Uq5..."**,
>           "targetOrigin":"http://instance.salesforce.com:8080"
>       },

I reckon you could use that SessionId against the instance URL with the SOAP APIs if the user has the required permissions.